# Can you choose watir commands through a variable?

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I'm fairly new to programming, and I'm not sure what keywords I should be looking for.

I'm doing something like this right now:

```
def click(text, type)
  b.span(:text=> text).click if type == 'span'
  b.button(:name=> text).click if type == 'button'
  b.image(:src=>text).click if type == 'image'
  b.button(:title=>text).click if type == 'title'
end
```

I don't like it because it isn't scaling very well. I want to do something like:

```
def click(text,type)
  b.type(:text=> text).click
end
```

It throws an undefined method error if I try to enter the type without quotes, but it's definitely not a string. How do I tell the script to use watir-webdriver span/button/image/etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to figure out exactly what it is you want to do with this method or why it's even necessary--or why your *type* parameter would ever be anything other than a string--but here's a way to help you clean up your code that's similar to what orde suggested.

Note that it's unclear what you're implying when you say "it's definitely not a string." If it's not a string, what is it? Where is it coming from that you are sticking it into this method's parameters without knowing what type of Object it is?

So... I'm assuming your *type* doesn't **have** to be a String object, so I made it so it takes symbols...

```
def click(text, type)
  types={span: :text, button: :name, image: :src, title: :title }
  @b.send(type, {types[type]=>text}).click
end
```

Comment: I tried this, it didn't seem to work. Hitting Google search button gave undefined local variable 'button'

Comment: You're going to need to be more specific about that error message. Can you provide the full stack trace and more of the code you've written? If you're sending #button to a Watir Browser object then #button should definitely be recognized.

In my answer, I assumed that you would know that @b would have to be defined at some point with:

@b = Watir::Browser.new

Comment: Another thing I assumed was that you would know that your _type_ parameter would have to be a Symbol--meaning you **have to** pass in _:button_ and not _'button'_ or _button_ as the second parameter of the method. I hope that's clear. If it's not, I suggest picking up a Ruby programming book and learn more about it.

Comment: Symbols are the thing I am looking for. I didn't know what the keyword was, so the question was designed to provide an example where a symbol is necessary... should I close this question or something? I have the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Ideally you accept one of our answers. Or, you should post your own answer (and accept it) if it is different from what we provided. That way this question will show up as "answered" and people in the future with a similar problem can learn from it. That's the Stack Overflow best practice.

Comment: Thanks. I just think that this is a terrible question, in retrospect. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you are calling your `click` method in your scripts, but here is a contrived example that seems to work:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

def click_method(element, text)
  @b.element(:text => "#{text}").click  
end

@b = Watir::Browser.new
@b.goto "http://www.iana.org/domains/reserved"

click_method("link", "Domains")
```

**EDIT:**

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

def method_not_named_click(el, locator, locator_val)
  if locator_val.is_a? String
    @b.send(el, locator => "#{locator_val}").click
  elsif locator_val.is_a? Integer
    @b.send(el, locator => locator_val).click
  end
end

@b = Watir::Browser.new
@b.goto "http://www.iana.org/domains/reserved"

method_not_named_click(:a, :text, "Domains")
method_not_named_click(:a, :index, 3)
```

Comment: Won't the `element` parameter get ignored? This would click the first element with text Domain regardless of element type.

Comment: Thx Justin.  I updated the answer (and slapped myself for using `element` as a parameter name).